# Aurelia Unit Test - How to mock a custom resolver

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, aurelia

Here is the class that I am trying to test:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {CrudResource, DependencyFactory} from 'utils';

let commonData = {};
    @inject(DependencyFactory.of(CrudResource))
    export class CommonDataCache {
        constructor(crudResourceFactory) {
            this.crudResource = crudResourceFactory('/Common');
        }
        data() {
            return Object.keys(commonData).length > 0 ? commonData :
                this.crudResource.get().then(response => {
                    commonData.clientEntities = response;
                    return commonData;
                });
        }
    }
```

I am attempting to write this test (posted only the relevant part for brevity):

```
beforeEach(() => {
        container = new Container();

        container.registerInstance('DependencyFactory.of(CrudResource)', new CrudResourceFactoryMock());

        templatingEngine = container.get(TemplatingEngine);

        cdc = templatingEngine.createViewModelForUnitTest(CommonDataCache);
    });
```

Basically, since my class is injecting a factory of the resource (the factory just allows me to configure the injected dependency on construction), I am attempting to pass in a mocked factory (which will pass in a mocked dependency).

The issue that I am facing is that somehow the CommonDataCache class is being instantiated with its regular dependency (as opposed to my mocked one). Somehow aurelia doesn't understand that I have registered a mocked factory for the `'DependencyFactory.of(CrudResource)'` resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aurelia unit test gone wrong (Karma/Jasmine)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271312/aurelia-unit-test-gone-wrong-karma-jasmine)

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't use Dependency injection in a Unit Test. I would create a mock and pass that to the constructor for `CommonDataCache`.

Once you start using the DI system, you're no longer creating Unit Tests, but are starting to create E2E tests.

Comment: Ok, but what if I have a custom element/attribute, don't I need to use the DI system? How could I new a custom element myself?